# Setup Github action : shivammathur/setup-php@v2 with composer image

Tags: php, docker, github-actions

Github Action.

I have a PHP Project (using Yii2 Framework) that I need to build into a docker image, which is those project also need MongoDB extension.

My plan is in Github Action - CI phase is like this:

- Commit to main branch
- Enable php extension
- Run composer install --no-dev
- Build docker image using dockerfile, which is in those dockerfile, I copy vendor`s folder into an image container,
- ..so on

So, for those, I start with a configuration: `01 - Init Composer.yml` like this:

```
name: Init composer
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  run-composer:
    name: composer initialization
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: composer:latest
      volumes:
        - ${{ github.workspace }}:/app
    steps:
              
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: PHP setup with Extension
        id: setup-php
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'
          extensions: mongodb-mongodb/mongo-php-driver@v1.9
          
      - name: Cache Composer packages
        id: composer-cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: vendor
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-php-

      - name: Running composer install
        run: composer install --no-dev
```

I got error like this:

```
Run shivammathur/setup-php@v2
/usr/bin/docker exec  fccfaf138a6147da33e0f9ca9add2947ae76ff4b439c3fe9c35f53042e6419fa sh -c "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"
/bin/bash /__w/_actions/shivammathur/setup-php/v2/src/scripts/run.sh

==> Setup PHP
/__w/_actions/shivammathur/setup-php/v2/src/scripts/linux.sh: line 216: sudo: command not found
✗ PHP Could not setup PHP 8.1
Error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

Any advise is so appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running inside the composer image, it doesn't have the sudo command to perform actions to compile the extension.

In action shivammathur/setup-php it is possible enable composer, [see tools support](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php#wrench-tools-support)

Try running it directly in ubuntu, setting the php and composer extension first.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here when running it  in self hosted server.

Looks like shivammathur already fixed in the "develop" branch ([see here](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/commit/dd0115673c4a47a832dff844189234f0e9b3966e))

It will be fixed in the next version, you can follow the issue about it [here](https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php/issues/688)